# Select dataframe rows by ongoing loop values with c()

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, row

I have a dataframe (timeseries_df) with over 300 rows and I have values (a1, a2, a3) as results from a loop.
The values a1, a2, a3 are numbers, for example a1=3, a2= 56, a3=120 and so on.

Now I want to select all rows from my dataframe with the values that are created from the loop.

It should look like this:

```
rows <- timeseries_df[c(a1, a2, a3, a4), ]
```

but i need it more automated, because the number of values from the loop are not always the same.

The function from the loop is called *near*
so when I try

```
for (m in 1:nrow(ts_niv)){
    
    rows <- timeseries_df[c(near), ]
  }
```

it works, but it overwrites the dataframe for each value (a1, a2) and in the end there is only a frame with the last value selected from the dataframe. I need a dataframe as a result with all rows selected by the values (a1, a2, a3) from the loop.

I think its not that complicated, but I'm still quite a beginner in dealing with R. Maybe someone can help me, fix that problem.

Comment: Can you post sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

## Assumptions and Clarifications

1. Since `near()` is inside a `for` loop using index `m`, and since `m` is related to the `ts_niv`, I assume that `near()` is a function of both `m` and `ts_niv`.
2. Since you have provided neither the definition of `near()` nor a sample of the data in `ts_niv`, nor a sample of the data in `timeseries_df`, let's use the following definitions for illustrative purposes:

```
require( purrr )        # for %>% and map

# a multi-variate time series
ts_niv <- ts( matrix( rnorm( 24 ), 8, 3 ), start = c( 1961, 1 ), frequency = 12 )

# a function that returns some row indexes from ts_niv
near <- function( index = m, data = ts_niv ){
  num_rows_to_return <- round( runif( 1, max = 6), 0 )
  round( runif( num_rows_to_return, min = 1, max = nrow( ts_niv )), 0 )
}

# another multi-variate time series
timeseries_df <- ts( matrix( rnorm( 300 ), 50, 6 ), start = c( 1961, 1 ), frequency = 12 )
```

## Getting the answers

```
# For each row in the time-series
seq( nrow( ts_niv )) %>% 

  # Get the row-index of interest
  map( ~near( index = ., data = ts_niv )) ->

   ragged_list
```

### The indexes

Here's what we get:

- a list that is long enough for one item per row of the time-series
- each item in the list is a vector of integers, representing row indexes to fetch from *timeseries_df*

```
ragged_list
#[[1]]
#numeric(0)         <--- near() returned no indexes for this row
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 7 3 6          <--- near() returned three indexes for this row
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 6 8 3 3        <--- near() returned four indexes for this row
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 2 7 2 6 8      <--- near() returned five indexes for this row
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 4 7 3 6        <--- near() returned four indexes for this row
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 6 1 1          <--- near() returned three indexes for this row
#
```

### The rows represented by those indexes

We can get row *j* from *timeseries_df* with `timeseries_df[ j, ]`.

To get several rows at once, we can use `timeseries_df[ a_vector_of_integers, ]`

So let's do what we did to get the row-indexes and instead of returning those indexes, let's return the rows to which they refer.

```
# For each row in the time-series
seq( nrow( ts_niv )) %>% 
  # Get the row-index of interest
  
  map( ~timeseries_df[ near( index = ., data = ts_niv ), ]) ->

    a_list_of_matrices
```

This generates a list of matrices.

```
a_list_of_matrices
#[[1]]                      near() returned no indexes for this row
#     Series 1 Series 2 Series 3 Series 4 Series 5 Series 6
#
#[[2]]                      near() returned three indexes for this row
#     Series 1 Series 2 Series 3  Series 4 Series 5 Series 6
#[1,]   0.5295  -0.2217   0.1995  0.875480  1.48813  -0.4781
#[2,]   0.5295  -0.2217   0.1995  0.875480  1.48813  -0.4781
#[3,]  -0.6974  -0.5784  -0.1910 -0.009228 -0.09915  -0.7863
#
#[[3]]                      near() returned four indexes for this row
#     Series 1 Series 2 Series 3 Series 4 Series 5 Series 6
#[1,]   0.8119   0.6454   1.6422  -0.9117  0.07844  -1.5139
#[2,]  -1.5977   1.4027  -0.4212  -1.7027  1.79133   0.2609
#[3,]  -0.1623   1.0213  -1.1960  -1.8157  0.07729   0.4734
#[4,]  -0.1623   1.0213  -1.1960  -1.8157  0.07729   0.4734
# ...
```

## Combining the answers

It is easy to combine these using `rbind()`:

```
do.call( rbind, a_list_of_matrices )
#      Series 1 Series 2 Series 3 Series 4 Series 5 Series 6
#[1,]   0.5295  -0.2217   0.1995  0.875480  1.48813  -0.4781
#[2,]   0.5295  -0.2217   0.1995  0.875480  1.48813  -0.4781
#[3,]  -0.6974  -0.5784  -0.1910 -0.009228 -0.09915  -0.7863
#[4,]   0.8119   0.6454   1.6422  -0.9117  0.07844  -1.5139
#[5,]  -1.5977   1.4027  -0.4212  -1.7027  1.79133   0.2609
#[6,]  -0.1623   1.0213  -1.1960  -1.8157  0.07729   0.4734
#[7,]  -0.1623   1.0213  -1.1960  -1.8157  0.07729   0.4734
# [8,]   0.6204  -0.8115   1.1573  0.40136  0.01218 -0.31174
# [9,]   0.8119   0.6454   1.6422 -0.91174  0.07844 -1.51386
#[10,]   0.8119   0.6454   1.6422 -0.91174  0.07844 -1.51386
#[11,]  -0.1623   1.0213  -1.1960 -1.81571  0.07729  0.47341
#[12,]  -0.1623   1.0213  -1.1960 -1.81571  0.07729  0.47341
#...
```